# Conditionally insert into table if column exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, idempotent

I'm trying to write an idempotent db migration script, which, among other things, needs to shuffle some data. Later in the script, one of the columns I'm selecting from is removed (the purpose of the migration is to move data from that column into a new place), so I have something like this (generated by EF Core):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'AName')
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO Foos (A, B)
     SELECT OldA, OldB FROM Bars
END

-- a little later in the script:

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'AnotherName')
BEGIN
      ALTER TABLE [Bars] DROP COLUMN [OldB];
END
```

However, this isn't as idempotent as I'd hoped it would be; the second time I run the script, it fails with an error on the first `INSERT` statement, since the `OldB` column doesn't exist on `Bars` anymore.

However, the guard clause above will *always* be false if `OldB` has been dropped, because in the same go as dropping `OldB`, we also insert that row into the migrations history (and yes, I've checked that this is true now too; the row exists). So the `INSERT` should *never* run without all columns it cares about existing.

How can I write an idempotent `INSERT` like the one above, that doesn't validate existence of all columns until it's actually run?

Comment: I was going to suggest using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if all columns exist:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] 
               WHERE [MigrationId] = N'AName')
BEGIN
     IF (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM sys.columns 
        WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('Bars')
          AND name IN ('OldA', 'OldB')) = 2
     BEGIN
          EXEC('INSERT INTO Foos (A, B)
          SELECT OldA, OldB FROM Bars');
     END
END

-- a little later in the script:

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] 
               WHERE [MigrationId] = N'AnotherName')
BEGIN
      EXEC('ALTER TABLE [Bars] DROP COLUMN [OldB]');
END
```

Comment: This still yields the same error; it seems it doesn't matter that I have a guard clause around the `INSERT` that will ensure it's never executed, it's still considered invalid just for being there. For example, wrapping the `INSERT` with `IF 0 = 1` still yields the error.

Comment: @TomasLycken Please check my edit. Wrapping it with dynamic SQL will solve name resolution problem and the check will be done at runtime.